# Wrapping 2d grid indices

Tags: c++, modulo

I have this function which i prototyped in python for navigating grid indexes. It works perfectly in python but due to the way the modulo operator handles negative numbers it falls down in c++. Can anyone suggest a modification that will make this work?

The function fails when coordinates `nx` and `ny` are negative.

```
int wrap_grid(int index, int x, int y, int nx, int ny) {

        //first calculate positon on row by adding nx -
        //assuming an infinite grid of indices (no limits or wrap)
        int a = (index + (y * nx));
        //then wrap around the width (x) of the row
        int b = a % (x * y);

        //now do column, calculate the bottom index of the column
        int start = b - b % y;
        //and the top index
        int limit = b - b % y + y;

        //now wrap the ny value around the columns
        return start + (b + ny) % (limit - start);
}
```

**EDIT: To explain function arguments**

`index` is the index of a rectangular grid, like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 11 | 17 |
| 4 | 10 | 16 |
| 3 | 9 | 15 |
| 2 | 8 | 14 |
| 1 | 7 | 13 |
| 0 | 6 | 12 |

`x` is the width of the grid, in this case 3.
`y` is the height of the grid, in this case 6.
`nx` is the coordinate grid square offset, so `nx = 1` is one grid square to the right, similar for `ny=1` is one grid square 'upwards'.

The return value is the new index number after transforming `index` with the coordinates `nx` and `ny`.

EDIT: updated function based on jwezorek's approach. Note, the only effective change (function factors aside) are the comparison operators which must allow zero values.

```
int wrap_grid(int index, int rows, int columns, int offset_x, int offset_y) {

    //index to grid coordinates always positive
    int x = (index / rows) + (offset_x);
    x = x >= 0 ? x : x + columns;

    int y = (index % rows) + (offset_y);
    y = y >= 0 ? y : y + rows;

    //grids to coords
    int column = x % columns;
    column = column >= 0 ? column : column + columns;

    int row = y % rows;
    row = row >= 0 ? row : row + rows;

    int bottom_of_column_index = column * rows;

    return bottom_of_column_index + row;
    }
```

Comment: What are `index`, `x`,`y`,`nx`, and`ny`?

Comment: and what is the return value?

Comment: the table isnt formatting in the answer, the preview looks fine. its basically a grid of index numbers from bottom to top and left to right starting at 0.

Comment: Use `x` and `nx` to calculate the new `x` value *first* (same with `y` and `ny`). *Then* do the index calculation. For negative values, add them to the row (or column) count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a mod function that will only give you non-negative values. To just do it the straight-forward way is like below (after moving your code around for clarity).

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int grid_coords_to_index(int cols, int rows, int x, int y) {
    // wrap the coordinates...
    int column = x % cols;
    column = column >= 0 ? column : column + cols;

    int row = y % rows;
    row = row >= 0 ? row : row + rows;

    int bottom_of_column_index = column * rows;
    return bottom_of_column_index + row;
}

std::tuple<int,int> index_to_grid_coords(int cols, int rows, int index) {
    // TODO: handle negatives correctly here too, if we cannot 
    // assume indices are positive.
    return { index / rows, index % rows };
}

int wrap_grid(int initial_index, int cols, int rows, int x_offset, int y_offset) {
    auto [x, y] = index_to_grid_coords(cols, rows, initial_index);
    return grid_coords_to_index(cols, rows, x + x_offset, y + y_offset);
}

int main()
{  
    /*
    5   11  17
    4   10  16
    3   9   15
    2   8   14
    1   7   13
    0   6   12

    index 9 is (1,3) so two to the left and one down should be 14 given wrapping

    */

    std::cout << wrap_grid(9, 3, 6, -2, -1) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This approach worked very well. I had to change the comparison operators from ```>``` to ```>=``` because zero indexes are allowed and would shift by a row or column above. I have updated the question with my function for reference. Much appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: i updated my code to use `>=` that was a bug.